# Should I include a job on my CV which only lasted 6 weeks?

Tags: resume

I am leaving a job only after 6 weeks as they over estimated my experience and capabilities. They were really nice about it: verbally promising to be really good refs. So I am leaving on good terms.

As I am new to city/country, I feel there is a a few pros in keeping it on my CV.

Local experience (however brief), local refs, leaving on good terms.

The cons are the obvious short tenure.

What makes the better resume?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is probably not a good idea to add it to your CV. Leads to awkward questions in the interview. Adds little value. Not a good selling point.

Comment: thanks Ed, what about the 'legality' of things?

Comment: A CV is not a legal document. It is a mechanism to sell yourself to get an interview. That is all it is. Anything on it should be accurate. But leaving stuff off means it is not inaccurate.

Comment: In some countries they expect a gapless CV with every position, even if it was for 1 week.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen Could you name a couple? I’m curious because I’ve never heard of that. What do people do if they didn’t have a job for a month?

Comment: @StellaBiderman Germany and Switzerland are the biggest example countries. If you didn't have a job, you would list it something like ``1 June 2018 - 30 June 2018: Unemployed``

Answer (score 2):

If the job was relevant to the new position and you can get a reference from someone there then sure put them down.